# Combined Tasks List Data View Web Part - SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, aggregation, cross-list, merge

I am looking to create a list that will show all outstanding tasks from multiple Task lists that are in multiple site-collections in Sharepoint Online/Office 365. I am aware that there are 3rd party solutions that provide this functionality but this isn't an option at present.

I believe I need to create a Data View Web Part in order to do this as it seems this is the preferred option for displaying multiple columns of data rather than the Content Query Web Part.

I have come across multiple articles about this but the majority are code snippets all with different approaches using SOAP, REST, SPDataSource and some in XML/HTML and others in C# which is quite confusing for a beginner to  SharePoint development.

What I'm really looking for is a step-by-step/idiots guide on how to do this in Sharepoint Designer 2013.

Comment: Have you considered Search? You can create a result source that grabs all the data you need, and you can create a custom display template to format the appearance.

Comment: Any suggested articles which detail how this could be done via Search and displayed in a list?